# How to unit test a function that creates a new coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to write a unit test for my ViewModel. It contains several functions that call `viewModelScope.launch` inside the body, like my example `doStuff`:

```
fun doStuff() {
    //synchronous stuff
    viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main) {
        doMoreStuff()
    }
}

suspend fun doMoreStuff() = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    db.getFromDB()
    result = result + 1
}
```

I'm not sure how to test this. Here is my current test:

```
    @Test
    fun `test doStuff`() {
        runBlocking {
            viewModel.doStuff()
        }
        coVerify { db.getFromDb() }
        Assert.assertEquals(viewModel.result, 1)
    }
```

And I am getting "java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed" showing that `getFromDb()` is not being called, and `result` is not being set either. I also tried removing the `runBlocking`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for coroutine tests there is a pattern for creating a `CoroutineTestRule`, which essentially overwrites the **Main Dispatcher** and basically you'll run everything in one thread in a blocking mode.

I'm not 100% sure, but in your specific case it might work with simply moving the `coVerify` and `assert` methods inside the `runBlocking` method:

```
  @Test
    fun `test doStuff`() {
        runBlocking {
            viewModel.doStuff()
            coVerify { db.getFromDb() }
            Assert.assertEquals(viewModel.result, 1)
        }
    }
```

But I'd check out this example also for coroutine tests: https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground/blob/master/common/src/androidTest/kotlin/com/halcyonmobile/multiplatformplayground/viewmodel/ApplicationsViewModelTest.kt